# Not able to create a python program to find the lcm

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a lcm finder but i failed can some one give me and idea for it

so this was wat i was able to create

```
class math:

    def lcm_finder(self, number1, number2):
        if number1 > number2:
            grater = number1
        elif number1 < number2:
            grater = number2
```

please tell me its ahead code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
def find_lcm(x, y):

   # choose the higher number
   if x > y:
       greater = x
   else:
       greater = y

   while(True):
       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
           lcm = greater
           break
       greater += 1

   return lcm

num1 = 22 # You can input the numbers if u want
num2 = 56

# call the function
print("L.C.M :", find_lcm(num1, num2))
```